# How to point Amazon EC2 Linux DISPLAY to X11 on my Macbook?

Tags: linux, unix, x11

I am trying to install Glassfish on my new Amazon EC2 Linux instance.

The installation is telling me to set the `DISPLAY` variable.

I determine my IP by using http://www.whatismyip.com (for example 123.45.67.89)

I open X11 on my Mac and I set the ip address in linux (eg export DISPLAY=123.45.67.89)

But the Glassfish installation is throwing an exception

```
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '123.45.67.89' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mac is likely not making X available via remote interfaces (a relatively sane default).  The idiomatic way to do this is to tunnel it over `ssh`, which has the handy benefit of relieving you of the burden of configuring the `DISPLAY` variable (not to mention saving you the embarrassment of typing your glassfish credentials in the clear!).

From your mac:

```
ssh -X user@remotehost
```

Now, on the `remotehost`:

```
./run_glassfish_somehow
```

Comment: I am trying that ssh command from my Macbook, but I am getting the message - "Permission denied (publickey)." Any advice?

Comment: Is it interactively asking for your password?  Do you have a key configured on the client that's absent from the server?  See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/39733/why-do-i-get-permission-denied-publickey-when-trying-to-ssh-from-local-ubunt